# How to apply background pattern image to html tooltip arrow?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am implementing a custom jquery plugin for tooltips. This plugin will show a tooltip box when mouse is hovered on a specific element. My tooltip block area has an arrow which is pointing towards base element.

I want to apply repeating texture image to entire tooltip including the arrow. 
I can assign pattern image to tooltip background but how can i assign it to the arrow.

My problem is more illustrated in following image :

[image]

Following is the code for arrow :
HTML:

```
<div class="tooltip_outer">
  <div class="tooltip_arrow"></div>
  <div class="tooltip_txt">Tooltip content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tooltip_outer {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  background: #000000 url(images/pattern.png);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px 3px;
  width: 135px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
}
.tooltip_arrow {
  top: -14px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  border-width: 7px;
  border-bottom-color: #000000;
  left: 50%;
}
.tooltip_txt {
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/LqX9Z/

Comment: If I understand you right, you want to add the repeated pattern to that raises tip part of the tool tip, but It looks like you already have it there. If the image is irrelevant, you would just add the CSS proporty of background-image as you did for the other div.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but hope it will be useful for people having the same issue.

I've made a codepen using scss and property clip-path where you can set the direction, the position and the size of the arrow, as well as the size of the border if you need one.

https://codepen.io/onyphlax/pen/OJbpbGR

```css
.tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  padding-bottom: calc(10px + 2px);
  background-color: fuchsia;
  position: relative;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - calc(10px + 2px)), calc(calc(50%) + calc(10px + 2px)) calc(100% - calc(10px + 2px)), calc(50%) 100%, calc(calc(50%) - calc(10px + 2px)) calc(100% - calc(10px + 2px)), 0 calc(100% - calc(10px + 2px)));
}
.tooltip__container {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -6px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, cyan, purple);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 10px), calc(50% + 10px) calc(100% - 10px), 50% 100%, calc(50% - 10px) calc(100% - 10px), 0 calc(100% - 10px));
}
.tooltip__content {
  padding: 1rem;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
  <div class="tooltip__container">
    <div class="tooltip__content">I'm a tooltip</div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With CSS you can't apply a background image to a border. Border is intended as border, not as shape.

You could use a DIV rotated by 45 deg as arrow, but with problems on old browsers.

Edit: I've found a new CSS3 propriety for add pattern images to borders, I think it's what you're looking for:

http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/border-images/